# Inititialize my R-function within an excel macro in REXCEL

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to create an Excel button that "sources" my R-function `analyzer.R` within the R session that is attached to the RExcel process by doing:

```
Sub Initialize()
  MsgBox "Initialize R my functions "
  RInterface.StartRServer
  RInterface.RRun "source(""C:\\Users\\analyzer.R"")"
  RInterface.StopRServer    
End Sub
```

the attached R-console throws the error:

```
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"
```

Note that if I run the command

```
source("C:\\\Users\\\analyzer.R")
```

directly within the R-session things work fine.

Comment: `/` works in pretty much everything, AFAIK. windows directories, sas, unix, r. good practice to use `/` all the time instead of "\" or "\\" (also doesn't mess up your formatting on stackexchange dot com)

Comment: someone can go ahead and post the comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but your problem wasn't \, it was that you used "".

what you wrote:

`RInterface.RRun "source(""C:\\Users\\analyzer.R"")"`

what VBA saw:

```
RInterface.RRun "source("
"C:\\Users\\analyzer.R"
")"
```

instead, try single quotes.

```
RInterface.RRun "source('C:\\Users\\analyzer.R')"
```